# Jenkins - Watching for SVN Branches

Tags: svn, branch, jenkins, apache-pig

Is there a way to get Jenkins to look for changes in all branches of an SVN project, much like it does with Git?

The Apache Pig Piggybank is a set of classes that are contributed to by the community, and add exntesion to specific versions of Apache Pig. Pig itself is released via Maven, so getting a specific version of it is never a problem. Piggybank on the other hand is not versioned, however there are branches for each version of Pig that it depends on.

I'd like to have Jenkins watch, and then build, for all branches in the Pig SVN repository. I'd really rather not have to keep an eye on new versions of Piggybank, and add a Jenkins job for each branch.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some elaboration along the lines of @Lars answer:

Create trigger job (let's call it *Trigger*) that will checkout every branch into a different directory in its workspace (by the way, you may create those directories manually in the workspace with `--depth=empty` option, then Subversion Plugin will still detect the changes, but won't checkout the code saving you space in case you have a lot of branches).

You can then use `SNV_REVISION_n` (where `n` is 1, 2, etc.; see [Subversion Plugin Documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin)) in a script that *Trigger* invokes as a build step to check which branch (or branches) have really changed (you need to store the results, of course, to be used in the next *Trigger* build).

Then you create only one job (let's call it *Worker*) that takes the branch name as a parameter. *Trigger* will invoke *Worker* via http with wget or curl with appropriate parameters (e.g. branch name).

Alternatively, you can have a *Trigger* job per branch and invoke *Worker* using [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin). The drawback is that you'll need to create a *Trigger* per branch and you'll have more SVN polling (unless you use [SVN push](http://jenkins-ci.org/node/212)). On the other hand you won't need to write a script that
checks which branch has changed and you can use [Blame Subversion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/BlameSubversion) to propagate the changeset from *Trigger* to *Worker* (and only changes relevant to the branch at that).

*Worker* will update/checkout the branch passed to it as a parameter manually (`svn co` etc.) and build.

This way you have only one job that does actual heavy lifting (which means easier maintenance, less bugs, etc.)

I employ this method in our build system. As we do not have more than 2 active branches at a time I use trigger per branch approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple repository locations to a single project and have them checked out to different directories. You would still have to add all the branches manually though.